# how do i fixed the problem on url if anyone of passing parameter is undefined?

Tags: parameters, angular7

my url with parameters  is like this:
http://192.168.1.87:8002/api/report/absent_report/&from+date=2019-01-23&to_date=2019-01-23&class=undefined&section=undefined

i want  url  with parameter likethis:
http://192.168.1.87:8002/api/report/absent_report/&from_date=2019-01-23&to_date=2019-01-23

so how i remove(or skip from url) those parameter from url whose value is not passed,only that type of  parameter is passed whose value is defined.like here on above in url some  parameter likethis: &class=undefined&section=undefined

but my goal is to remove if it is undefined .Also i have posted a  image of code below

[service.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5Qar.png)

[service.ts file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9imvo.png)

Guide me  with  answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution to fix this above problem

```
get(feepaid_report: FeepaidReport): Observable<FeepaidReport[]> {
  var url = `${this._feepaidreportUrl}/?`

   for(var key in feepaid_report){

      var val = feepaid_report[key];
       if (typeof(val) !=='undefined'){
        url = url + key + '=' + val + '&'
      }

    }



  const options = this._utils.makeOptions(this._headers);
    return this._http.get(url, options).pipe(
      map((res: Response) => res.json()),
      tap(
        data => this.afterGetRequest(),
        error => { console.log(error); }
      ));
  }
```